# Mac SQL Operations Studio Import

Tags: csv, import, azure-data-studio

I've widely searched for this feature, but cannot find any info. Is it possible to import csv in SQL Operations Studio (Mac)?

Comment: Not at the moment. See https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/issues/785

Answer (score 2):

Yes,CHECK THE LEFT CORNER OF THE SCREEN AFTER OPENING SQLOPS, YOU'LL FIND A MENU STARTING WITH SERVERS AND ENDING WITH EXTENSIONS, CLICK ON EXTENSIONS AND YOU CAN FIND **SQLOPS RECOMMENDATIONS (STAR SYMBOL)**,CHOOSE SQL SERVER IMPORTS, THEN INSTALL IT AND ENABLE IT.

ABOVE MENTIONED PROCESS TAKES 2 TO 3 MINS .AFTER THAT REACH BACK TO QUERY PAGE AND PRESS (CNTRL + I), YOU WILL GET OPTIONS TO IMPORT DATA.

Comment: No need to scream